# What is the relationship between an entity_id and a product_id

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

Looking over the magento 1.5 schema I cannot seem to figure out how a product_id relates to an entity_id.

In all my test cases I can verify that the product_id and entity_id are equal (the same int).  But I am guessing that somewhere this is a relationship and even though they are equal in my test cases, it's likely this is only a coincidence and not something I should depend on.

In what tables or relationships can I find what this link is so that I can write a reliable query.

I'm just looking for something like this... tho it probably won't be this simple.

```
select entity_id from <wherever> where product_id = 1234
```

Comment: "Write a reliable query", I must know more.

Comment: I was trying to update one of my custom attributes based on the is_in_stock field in the inventory table.  The attributes are stored by entity_id but the in stock status is stored by product_id.  So, until I verified that these are the same I figured I was going to have to do my updates via subquery.  But, alas, it was way easier than I thought.

Comment: In short I saved myself 2 hours of manual labor by spending 2 hours researching an update query that ran in several milliseconds.  All in all a fair trade :) since I learned something new.

Comment: Sure. The FK for products will always have to be `catalog_product_entity.entity_id`; nut now you know that with certainty!

Comment: Most of the time they are the same, but when you use the Schedule New Update feature in the background, they become inconsistent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per [Magento forum post by a Magento Team member](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/21033/) entity_id on the EAV side is in fact the same as the product_id on the catalog product end.  So, there you go.